# How to pass multiple params in Fn when I using Python map(Fn, Iterable)?

Tags: python, dictionary

As for `map(Fn, Iterable)`, my `Fn()` is fllowing:

```
def Fn(x, k):
    return x+k
```

But, if I want to use the `Fn()` in `map()`, the code could not like this:

```
map(Fn(Iterable, k), Iterable)
```

It means that how can I do if I want to use the param `k`? THX!

Comment: Perhaps you should describe your actual task rather than how you think it should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some possibilities

```
def fn(x,k):
   return x+k 

In [1095]: k=10  # in global space

In [1096]: map(lambda x: fn(x,k), [1,2,3])
Out[1096]: <map at 0xb263e04c>   # ops, py3, need

In [1097]: list(map(lambda x: fn(x,k), [1,2,3]))
Out[1097]: [11, 12, 13]
```

I prefer list comprehensions to map:

```
In [1100]: [(lambda x: fn(x,k))(x) for x in [1,2,3]]
Out[1100]: [11, 12, 13]

In [1101]: [fn(x,k) for x in [1,2,3]]
Out[1101]: [11, 12, 13]
```

or if both x and k come from iterables, we can join them with zip:

```
In [1102]: [fn(x,k) for x,k in zip([1,2,3],[10,20,30])]
Out[1102]: [11, 22, 33]
```

I was going to suggest `functools.partial`, but I don't think I can use that with the 2nd positional argument.  I can use it to partially define the 1st argument (in this case it doesn't matter).

```
In [1107]: from functools import partial

In [1111]: [partial(fn, 1)(k) for k in [10,20,30]]
Out[1111]: [11, 21, 31]

In [1112]: list(map(partial(fn, 1),[10,20,30]))
Out[1112]: [11, 21, 31]
```

If I change `fn` so `k` becomes a keyword argument

```
def fn(x,k=0):
    return x+k

In [1114]: [partial(fn, k=10)(x) for x in [1,2,3]]
Out[1114]: [11, 12, 13]
```

And similarly for `map`.

If I define `fn` so it takes a tuple, I could use zip with map:

```
def fn(args):
   x,k=args
   return x+k

In [1117]: list(map(fn,zip([1,2,3],[10,20,30])))
Out[1117]: [11, 22, 33]
```

Comment: If `fn()` really is what is given, the order of arguments doesn't matter...`functools.partial()` might apply after all.

Comment: Yes, that's what I realized after a bit more experimentation.

Comment: That keyword solution is actually quite good.  You don't even need to change the definition of `fn()`, however.

Comment: @zondo - that's true for Py3.  Py2 isn't as flexible.  In py2, the distinction between positional and keyword arguments is sharper.

Comment: Since `k` is already the last element, that doesn't interfere with how the positional argument is given.  I tested in Python 2.7.6, and it worked for me.